# R - Index position with condition

Tags: r, indexing, conditional-statements

I've a data frame like this

```
w<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

i would like an index position starting after value 1.

```
output : NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

ideally applicable to a data frame.

Thanks

edit : w is a data frame,

roughly this function

```
m<-as.data.frame(w)
m[m!=1] <- row(m)[m!=1]
m
    w
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   1
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
11 11
12 12
13  1
14 14
15 15
16 16
17 17
18  1
19 19
20 20
21 21
22 22
23 23
24 24
25 25
26 26
```

but with a return to 1 when value 1 is matching.

```
> m
    w wanted
1   1      NA
2   2      NA
3   3      NA
4   4      NA
5   5      NA
6   1      1
7   7      2
8   8      3
9   9      4
10 10      5
11 11      6
12 12      7
13  1      1
14 14      2
15 15      3
16 16      4
17 17      5
18  1      1
19 19      2
20 20      3
21 21      4
22 22      5
23 23      6
24 24      7
25 25      8
26 26      9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given data including repeated 1's and non-sequential input, the following works:

```
m[9,1] <- 100
m[3,1] <- 55
m[14,1] <- 60
m[14,1] <- 60
m[25,1] <- 1
m[19,1] <- 1

m$result <- 1:nrow(m) - which(m$w == 1)[cumsum(m$w == 1)] + 1
```

But if the data does not start on 1:

```
m[1,1] <- 2
```

Then this works:

```
firstone <- which(m$w == 1)[1]
subindex <- m[firstone:nrow(m),'w'] == 1
m$result <- c(rep(NA,firstone-1),1:length(subindex) - which(subindex)[cumsum(subindex)] + 1)
```

Comment: Could you help me to apply this function on each column of a data frame ?

Comment: You'll need to use one of the apply functions. Probably just apply with MARGIN = 2.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that the data is ordered in the way shown in example.

```
m$wanted <- with(m, ave(w, cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(w) <0)), FUN=seq_along))
m$wanted
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make an implicit assumption about the data? i.e. that values in w are ordered increasing within each block started by a 1? Not sure if that matters but perhaps worth mentioning

Comment: @beginneR I guess the OP is updating the dataset after I posted the solution.

Comment: Possible.. but +1 for a good solution if that assumption is valid

Comment: Thanks....it's a good solution. I just have to adapt to start the count from the first 1 value...but, it's very good..thnaks so much. It's so appreciated !